# bootstrap dual listbox after unselect not removing from post array but showing removed on submit

Tags: jquery, bootstrap-duallistbox

I am checking bootstrap-duallistbox and facing issue (I am using this in Laravel blade) :

HTML/JS :

```
<form role="form" method="post" id="demoform" action="@if(isset($role->id)){{ route('admin.tenant.roles.update', ['role' => $role->id]) }}@else{{ route('admin.tenant.roles.store') }}@endif" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    @if(isset($role->id))
        @method('PUT')
    @endif

    @csrf
    <select multiple="multiple" size="10" name="duallistbox_demo1[]">
    <option value="option1" selected="selected">Option 1</option>
    <option value="option2">Option 2</option>
    <option value="option3" selected="selected">Option 3</option>
    <option value="option4">Option 4</option>
    <option value="option5">Option 5</option>
    <option value="option6" selected="selected">Option 6</option>
    <option value="option7" selected="selected">Option 7</option>
    <option value="option8">Option 8</option>
    <option value="option9">Option 9</option>
    <option value="option0" selected="selected">Option 10</option>
    </select>
    <br>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default btn-block">Submit data</button>
</form>
<script>
    var demo1 = $('select[name="duallistbox_demo1[]"]').bootstrapDualListbox();
    $("#demoform").submit(function() {
    alert($('[name="duallistbox_demo1[]"]').val());
    //   return false;
    });
</script>
```

This is showing like this :

[image]

When I use filter using key '1', show like this :

[image]

Now I unselect both 'option1' or 'option10' one by one, and unselected showing working fine, Like this :

[image]

Now I click on 'submit data' button, then it's showing right data in alert 'option 3', 'option 6' or 'option 7' is selected, Like this :

[image]

Now I click on alert 'ok' and redirect to controller and print request data, like this :

```
public function update(Request $request)
{
    echo '<pre>';
    print_r($request->all());
    die;
}
```

Showing this response :

```
Array
(
    [_method] => PUT
    [_token] => 5qyR76PyN4J0g65AgPMKUKw1GfiSGRyXsFsrsvAa
    [duallistbox_demo1] => Array
        (
            [0] => option1
            [1] => option3
            [2] => option6
            [3] => option7
        )

)
```

In this response as showing 'option1' was unselected by me but in post values is still exist.

I unselected 'option1' or 'option10' both for removing and 'option10' is unselected from post value too but 'option1' not removing from post value, What is issue ?

Thank you!